# When downloading files in the background, I can’t get a list of active downloads. UWP

Tags: file, uwp, download, background-task

When downloading files in the background, I can’t get a list of active downloads. ActiveDownloads = System._COMobject. What am i doing wrong?

```
 List<DownloadOperation> activeDownloads = new List<DownloadOperation>();
 IReadOnlyList<DownloadOperation> downloads = null;
     try
        {
         downloads = await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();
         if (downloads?.Count > 0)
             {
              foreach (DownloadOperation download in downloads)
                  {
                    activeDownloads.Add(download);
                   }
             }
         }
```

try use BackgroundTransferGroup and get the same result

```
 IEnumerable<DownloadOperation> activeDownloads = BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsForTransferGroupAsync(backgroundTransferCompletionGroup).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Hello, when the application is downloading in the background, since it is no longer in the UI thread, the communication between the two is through the COM interface, so it will be displayed as `COMObject` type when debugging. You can extract the data through ForEach traversal. Is the content you obtained cannot be traversed?

Comment: @Richard Zhang - MSFT , there is one property is output (m_ObjectToDataMap = null)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, you may be confused when debugging, Visual Studio shows `downloads` type is not `IReadOnlyList<DownloadOperation>`, but `System._ComObject`.

This is because `BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync` is the data obtained through the COM interface, so Visual Studio will display as `System._ComObject`, this is only a temporary state.

When debugging, if you expand `downloads`, you will see `m_ObjectToDataMap = null`, which is also the result of Visual Studio's inference based on the current context. Usually, we do not need to consider the type of `System._ComObject` when developing, the application will convert it to `IReadOnlyList<DownloadOperation>` type after obtaining the data.

The result returned by `BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync()` is null, indicating that there is currently no pending download collection associated with the background transfer group.

There are two main points to note here.

The first is the download pending. This means that you have created a `DownloadOpeartion` and downloaded it, but terminated before completed (such as close the application). The next time you start the application, you can get the last unfinished download list through the `GetCurrentDownloadsAsync` method. But if you run a download at the same address when the application starts, it will replace the last unfinished download, because `BackgroundDownloader` does not support concurrent downloads of the same Uri.

The second is that the download list you obtained is not in a specific group, otherwise you cannot get it through the `GetCurrentDownloadsAsync` method.

Comment: i start my background task every 15 minutes, and if I use  `await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();`, i get `m_ObjectToDataMap = null` too(

Comment: Hi, do you mean that you created BackgroundDownloader in BackgroundTask? This is not a recommended practice. BackgroundDownloader can only be run during the lifecycle of the application. It is recommended to perform BackgroundDownloader related download operations while the application is running.

Comment: Yes, I do. Why is it a bad practice?

Comment: `BackgroundDownloader` will stop the ongoing download after the application is closed. After restarting the application, it can detect the unfinished download and continue the download. This behavior shows that `BackgroundDownloader` cannot download when the application is not running. `BackgroundTask` and application are not in the same process, `BackgroundDownloader` cannot perform download tasks in `BackgroundTask`

Comment: and if the application does not turn off? It is either collapsed or works

Comment: Hello, BackgroundTask runs in the Windows runtime component, which is relatively isolated from the application itself. That `BackgroundDownloader` is suitable for running in UWP application ontology (Application), rather than Windows runtime components